# Python script running in a Docker container not saving files to the correct path

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I have a python Flask app running inside a docker container (on Ubuntu 18.04) that is supposed to save files to a local Ubuntu directory. Another function is to read those files. For example, the directory could be /$USER/home or /root etc.

I have tried using different variations of the "docker run" command. The one that seemed to work remotely correctly was the following one.

docker run --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb -v ~/:/home -i -t --network=host mobile-forensics:latest

My python function for saving a file is as follows.

```py
def save_file(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
```

The function for reading a file is as follows.

```py
def read_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as stream:
     for line in stream:
         print(line)
```

The issue is that the app is supposed to save the files at the path specified in the code but it is saving them at incorrect paths. For example, if I specify the path to be "/home", instead of saving the files at "/home", the app saves them at paths such as

"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee1c3c4947043a1475e41d93fdbcc2cbb76c34aa49a42d108ac743921ce36b6f/diff/home/..."

The same issue is prevalent when reading files. The app is not reading them from the correct path. I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: `~/:/home` doesn't seem quite right? Is it a typo?

Comment: do you have an `USER`section in your Dockerfile?

Comment: I just check with official python image with above mounting path and its working fine, what is your Host os and python version `
`def save(filename, contents):  
    fh = open(filename, 'w')  
    fh.write(contents)  
    fh.close()  
  
save('file.name', 'some stuff') ` it save them in current directory while read also working fine `def read_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as stream:
     for line in stream:
         print(line)
read_file('/root/file.name')
`

Comment: one thing more by mounting `~/:/home ` while never mount `/var/lib/docker/overlay` which is only accessible by host os. may you are running Docker container from not home bath but somewhere else.

Comment: @knh190 Double checked. Seems to work for me

Comment: @LinSel No, I do not have a USER section in my Dockerfile. Can you please guide me on how to add one?

Comment: @Adiii I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6.7 (host) and python3-alpine (docker). I am not running the docker container from /home. I am running it from directories such as /home/user/someDir etc. I would like to add though that any file that the script saves does get saved directly in the /home directory, not in the subdirectory that I run the container from (directories like /home/user/someDir etc).

Comment: So I will suggest running first without mounting, and verify thing work as per your expectation and then run using mouting.